# Pivot table data filter showing unused dates

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

Normally when I create a pivot table and filter on a date field, it only shows me dates which are in my data - this is useful and relevant because my data might only come through weekly for example.
I've just changed the data source on a pivot table that was behaving just so, from a power query to a connection with direct SQL (not sure what this is officially called).  The data is from the same collection of dates, but now when I access the date filter I see every date in the year displayed, as well as a <date and at the end a >date

Why has it changed, and how can I set it back to only show valid dates from my data set?

[image: 1]

for reference, the source dates are:

[image]

Comment: Are you using PowerPivot? How are you connecting to the SQL Server?

Comment: black magic ... seriously though, it says it is called a Database Query. Previously it was through what I thought is a Power Query - is that the same thing as a Power Pivot?   I have another Pivot Table connected to another Database Query that has  data filter behaving as I like (just exposing dates actually in the data)..

Comment: Do you group date in pivot table? If yes, please ungroup date to check this issue.

Comment: @James, this behavior normally occurs because you are using a data model in PowerPivot which has a time dimension table. The other thing I can think of is if you are actually connecting to an SSAS cube or other OLAP database, which is also using a time dimension. Can you edit your post with details of the connection? Obvs remove sensitive info.

Comment: @Emily I am grouping by ReportDt in the SQL command, but not in the pivot table

Comment: @FlexYourData this is connecting to a Teradata database and the field ReportDt is a Date field. As mentioned, I have a similar query to s similar Teradata table/Date field that is not displaying this way.

Answer (score -1):

In your raw data format your dates as text refresh pivot table data, format your data as date and refresh again your pivot table. For some strange reason it works.